# Mobile Safari crash when changing video tag source dynamically

Tags: javascript, ios, html5-video, mobile-safari

I've recently been trying to solve an issue where a piece of code that handles dynamic video source change:

```
vid.src = "some_movie_url";
```

eventually causes mobile safari to crash.

The flow is a bit complex so I'm not publishing it here (too many async/event callback handling).

The actual question is this, I see in the device logs the following exception being thrown:

> "An AVPlayerItem cannot be associated with more than one instance of AVPlayer"

What action in mobile safari on a video tag may cause such an issue?

I see many question where Objective C native apps are involved, but non where mobile safari causes this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you're using JavaScript to simply replace the `src` attribute of the video element using DOM manipulation, perhaps you could get around this by instead removing the video node altogether, creating a new video node with the `src` attribute you want, and attaching that to the DOM.

Something along these lines:

```
var oldVidNode, vidNodeParent, newVidNode, newVidSrc;
oldVidNode = document.querySelector("video");
vidNodeParent = oldVidNode.parentNode;
vidNodeParent.removeChild(oldVidNode);
newVidNode = document.createElement("video"); 
newVidSrc = document.setAttribute("src", "foo.m4v");
vidNodeParent.appendChild(newVidNode);
```

Comment: While this might work it's not a valid option for me, cause I'm dealing a big system and thus can't mitigate this change and it adds additional bootstrapping for handling the transitions between the elements. Thanks!